# What's the format of the blacklist file in apk2bar command?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

If you refer to this link, 
http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/converting_apk_to_bar_files_1766001_11.html
in the command,

```
apk2bar <Android_app_or_folder> [<compatibility_exceptions>] [<Android_SDK_folder>] [<blacklist file>] [-t <bar folder>] [-w[1-5]] [-a <author name>][-d [<debug-token file>]] [-m] [-rv] [-etr] [-etl] [-etn] [-ci] [-la<n>] [-R] [-os <version>]
```

I would like to know what's the format of the **blacklist file** that needs to be passed. It's not explained in the page.

Thanks.

Comment: You can see one if you look inside the Apk2Bar jar file, it's in XML

Comment: I looked into the Apk2Bar jar file. I was able to find the format of Apk2Bar_compatibility_excepts.xml. They also have an xsd file for that. But can't find any info about the blacklist file.